# Criação de projetos em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, cms

Preciso criar um sistema que será o seguinte:

- Uma página de visualização do usuário comum que irá acessar o site com um login e senha para sua área
- Uma página onde uma empresa X irá verificar seus usuários cadastrados, adicionar informações, etc.
- Uma página onde o administrador do sistema irá controlar e adicionar novos módulos, como um CMS de atualização.

Neste caso, seria melhor eu criar projetos diferentes ou através de um projeto eu consigo gerenciar todos estes níveis mesmo que eles não sejam pertencentes a um mesmo ambiente?

Comment: Aparentemente um sistema só com camadas de acesso da conta de tudo isso.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente, você precisará de um único sistema.

No que diz respeito ao login de usuários, recomendo o uso do Devise, que é uma gem para autenticação de usuários. Pode ser que você também se interesse também pelo CanCan, que pode ser integrada facilmente ao Devise (caso use Rails 4, use a gem CanCanCan - https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan - que está atualizada e sendo ativamente mantida pela comunidade).

Quanto à parte de verificar usuários cadastrados, o RailsAdmin (https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) pode ser uma boa solução.

Por fim, vale a pena dar uma olhada no Comfortable Mexican Sofa (https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa) para trabalhar com CMS.